# How do I run cljs.test cases from a test directory in the figwheel repl?

Tags: testing, clojurescript, leiningen, figwheel

I'm trying to get started with a unit-tested clojurescript project, based on the [figwheel quickstart](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Quick-Start), but with some tests added. I tried, successfully, to add a basic cljs.test case (`test-numbers` from [the cljs.test doc](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Testing#writing-tests)) directly into my main file, `core.cljs`. When I broke it out into another file for tests only, however, I could not run it from the figwheel repl. Following is the current state of the relevant files, and my repl interaction. What do I need to change so that I can have runnable tests in a separate file from my implementation?

project.clj:

```
(defproject wheel "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.170"]]
  :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.2"]
            [lein-figwheel "0.5.0-1"]]
  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} [:target-path "out" "resources/public/cljs"]
  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{:id "dev"
              :source-paths ["src/main" "src/test"]
              :figwheel true
              :compiler {:main "wheel.core"
                         :asset-path "cljs/out"
                         :output-to "resources/public/cljs/main.js"
                         :output-dir "resources/public/cljs/out"}}]})
```

src/main/core.cljs:

```
(ns wheel.core
  (:require[cljs.test :refer-macros [deftest is testing run-tests]]))

(.log js/console "Hey Seymore")

(deftest test-dev-numbers
  (is (= 1 1)))
```

src/test/test.cljs:

```
(ns wheel.test
  (:require [cljs.test :refer-macros [deftest is testing run-tests]]))

(deftest test-numbers
  (is (= 1 1)))
```

after calls to `lein clean` and `rlwrap lein figwheel`:

```
cljs.user=> (in-ns 'wheel.core)
nil
wheel.core=> (run-tests)

Testing wheel.core

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
nil
wheel.core=> (test-dev-numbers)
nil
wheel.core=> (in-ns 'wheel.test)
nil
wheel.test=> (run-tests)

Testing wheel.test
#object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot read property 'test_numbers' of undefined]
wheel.test=> (test-numbers)
#object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot read property 'test_numbers' of undefined]
wheel.test=>
```

I was expecting the exact same results from running the tests within the wheel.test namespace as I had from running them in the wheel.core namespace.

Please note also that this is an incremental step - Once I understand how this works, I intend to set up a separate build configuration for test so I can run the tests separately - I'm just trying to take small steps, and I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: For the sake of experiment, if you switch `:main wheel.core` to be `:main wheel.test`, does that help? Also not refreshing the browser after changes - is something that trips me up.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I should have mentioned, I did try that. Same results - the test in wheel.core runs and the one in wheel.test errors out.

Comment: Another thing to try is having a build id that is "test", as well as the "dev" one you already have.

Comment: welp, i was able to add a "test" build id and pass the test on it. but I can't run _the same test_ under the "dev" build id, even though "dev" and "test" now have exactly the same properties except for their `output-to` and `output-dir` keys ("resources/public..." vs "resources/test...") - is there a caching thing not taken care of by lein clean that I'm missing?

Comment: If you `output-to` something different i.e. different .js file, then you might need a different markup (html) file to statically serve it from??

Comment: Yeah, I have a copy of the index.html file sitting in both the test/ and public/ subdirectories of resources/ and I'm loading the proper one for whatever build config I wish to exercise. current repl interaction from within the "dev" build target:
cljs.user=> (in-ns 'wheel.test)
nil
wheel.test=> (test-wheel-one)
WARNING: Use of undeclared Var wheel.test/test-wheel-one at line 1 <cljs repl>
#object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined]

Comment: In my experience each build gives a `ns` you can `(in-ns the-ns)` to and call functions. Trying from other namespaces gives the error you are getting. So for each `ns` I want to *REPL* (verb) in, I have a different build id. You might be experiencing the same limitation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104356/discussion-between-traffichazard-and-chris-murphy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience each build gives a ns you can `(in-ns 'the-ns)` to and call functions. Trying from other namespaces gives the error you are getting. So for each ns I want to REPL (verb) in, I have a different build id. You might be experiencing the same limitation.

(above is simply last comment from discussion).